# How to embed an ASCII logo into an ASCII-armored RSA key?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, rsa, public-key-encryption

The cryptoparty site publishes an RSA key with an ASCII art logo embedded in it. Is there a way to put arbitrary characters in an ASCII-armored RSA key?

From https://github.com/cryptoparty/handbook

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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| |Jh751ms0wkds3Snl+6qBy/3HnI48qb
jnjkjdadap/ __| '__| | | | '_ \| __/ _ \n98sau98u98a98798782hiuh 
jxxccdsad| (__| |  | |_| | |_) | || (_) |a86K2Mzwj+99uhjk1hj1hjs
akjskm098h\___|_|   \__, | .__/ \__\___/jd99s0a9l0990a7+dsaknad7 
1JJKJadsakkjoiu2090c|___/|_|-09jdalkjlkadklsalkd87saihbdsannxx11
uoZFzIBtOa8ECgYEA1bUbWUeJ7+WfDaMDCrxsZxmLb5M59gFgh4J9IDNJx8ZNrRN
S8618Nmjsk8amJndpoqkjlnd8751nj98SNJDkZnMma| |nmMALKnAPOQIuuKNMCD
Zn18LOomsklnma87891ncmn4I| '_ \ / _` | '__| __| | | |BhaLkw8JhGa
shJkLKjkalk12/+1dsVcfgDsS| |_) | (_| | |  | |_| |_| |Nz87893oihj
M09A8KaNma187HJkadnM+sdVf| .__/ \__,_|_|   \__|\__, |10Kla+4lsdN
cmMN1Janbsd82HgdfG81445Mn|_|0Kla/sHaj243676HaK1|___/aZdhjkaZ817d
tUY1xI/zRRZvw88GajezKm3oiRjdppiLVqSwYG6NRkoZvGkTUUljq60klkjee+5T
OTGIrldw2/YfI5iDMCvo0yBJVhv28XCIqy3Bd3JlXO+ygwlCqvrSuMDI8uE6KW07
tDvEidtFmkr/sMAxxhACu0zqd5wKBgQCV3ruJpUh6zYNtWbj8efLChRHA+wCXwJi
kFgFlBYMK407EIyQmLFh4PzwWsN7AXghCAwKnRiBIsshx0xuvW4Erbr1PaUicKLj
fuREsMg694545454344kdCxwg5Q0Azp4345445W98PR7gLSwj6EmkslgGcnyChFv
tnCMEPf6dfgedfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg4dfgdfgd JgkQKBgB5KCUjrVMG8x
icZ+zUTGcI5iDMCvereeerereerrIqy3Bd3JlXO+ygwlCqOCzlzV+zWvpLbO/slx
CIhi+aLMWI5asdasdarqwer23rwv28XCIqy3Bd3JlXO+ygwlCqe5KTbXzpyjxoAW
N9Pw0/LxI5iDMCvo0yBJVhv28XCrtrtert34lXO+ygwlCqLxXsgtipa1WEpdKguv
iNChiXuqOMlo9Ie0Ou9RNCKCs6eiK6xijeZiBDFVcWF4dVThM1lkiWw394ovn7Bd
AJ1BOAMF06ZK1/bJWZgWA0O0UAIfDIYMqmooaof7YgsxgLz+ZcUvFk33Snl+6qBy
/3HnI48qbnwtrjE8CgYE+XdpuUwlEzwuv5xD1eDqh0Y9/yE7yAmcHlsrdWcFAtyz
FNU9lUE/M+AEoAGtIV/rLzVI2G18ZduTfbK/kXxZatpamEgPAudc/HrwkkdkxJzD
uG5nDM4U
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid key; backslashes (`\`) are not allowed in the Base64 encoding.

Furthermore, if it were valid, it would be an unencrypted *private* key; *publishing* it on a website would defeat its purpose …